# Eclipse Maven WTP plugin not refreshing resources when switching profile

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-wtp, maven-eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a web application using Eclipse Juno and Maven-WTP plugin. This application has a header image and I also have two Maven profiles. Those profiles permit changing the header image, because they point to a different directory, where the image is located. That's how they are configured:

```
<profile>
    <id>local</id>
    <properties>
        <imagen.cabecera.dir>src/main/resources/styles/headers/example1</imagen.cabecera.dir>
    </properties>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>local2</id>
    <properties>
        <imagen.cabecera.dir>src/main/resources/styles/headers/example2</imagen.cabecera.dir>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

The idea is when I change the active profile in my *.m2/settings.xml* to have the header file changed as well. The active profile is configured like that:

```
<activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>local</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

If I change the active profile and do `mvn clean install` everything works like a charm in project's target directory. However, the problem comes with Maven-WTP plugin. This plugin is taking the file from `webapp/images` directory, and looks like when I change the active profile is not getting the new one. It seems the WTP plugin is not updating the file here, so I get the old one displayed in the browser, even I do a `clean install`. This is my **pom.xml** configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${imagen.cabecera.dir}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>cabecera.jpg</include>
                        </includes>
                        <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/header</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/header</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>cabecera.jpg</include>
                        </includes>
                        <targetPath>/images</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Does anybody know about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maven **Eclipse WTP Plugin** is getting the data to deploy from *webapp* directory. The clue is that this directory is not being cleaned when executing `mvn clean install`, because Maven only cleans *target* directory. The trick is [forcing Maven to clean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5702741/1199132) the resources I'm going to update too.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <filesets>
            <fileset>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/images</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>cabecera.jpg</include>
                </includes>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably will need to update your Maven project configuration via:

> right click on your project -> **Maven -> Update Project**

[image]

Comment: It works on me but if I wanna do just via console?