# Remove or delete resource files from target directory using pom file

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have two profiles in pom.xml, and I have some resource files which I have added into target resource directory: `${project.build.outputDirectory}/resources` during execution of the first profile. What I need to do is remove those resource files during execution of the second profile.
Is there any way to remove or delete existing files from target directory?

Answer (score 49):

I do agree with Matthew's observations, but I got the impression that the original poster was asking how to automate execution of `clean` during (normal) "execution" of a profile.

You can define a [plugin execution](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) for the Maven Clean Plugin. It is normally only bound to `clean`, but by defining a plugin execution you can bind `clean:clean` (that is the `clean` goal of the `clean` plugin) to whichever [lifecycle phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) you want. The documentation of the Maven Clean Plugin has [an example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/usage.html#Running_the_Clean_Plugin_automatically_during_a_build) of how to do this. The documentation also has [an example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html) of deleting additional files. Merged the two looks like this:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>auto-clean</id>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
         <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
         <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>some/relative/path</directory>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I've found you need to use `<excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>` in the configuration otherwise entire `target` directory will get deleted, too.

Comment: Well, sure. But the `target` folder is something you'd want to see deleted upon an `mvn clean` anyway.

Comment: This isn't about executing `mvn clean`, this is about deleting a specific file/folder when executing an arbitrary phase, e.g., `mvn package` - you may not want to clean the whole project and have to recompile.

Comment: Fair enough, I had to go back and read my own answer better to get that :)

Comment: I think this answer is better than the accepted since it is a generic solution, and responds well to the question that is generic as well, and not a solution for the `maven-antrun-plugin`.
@SanderVerhagen can you add the excludeDefaultDirectories as daiscog suggests?

Answer (score 42):

I got the solution..!!

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <tasks>
                <delete>
                    <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}/resources" includes="*.xml" />
                </delete>
            </tasks>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

for reference - http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html

Comment: Generally, in Maven, you'd prefer a declarative solution, over just coding it out (which plugins for like Ant, Groovy, etc.) let you do.

Comment: This post is totally correct but should be updated to use the target since task is deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, you can just replace `tasks` with `target`, and this will work. I was trying to delete if a file exists, and I ended up using `<delete failonerror="false">`.

Answer (score 20):

`mvn clean` will remove the `target` directory (and therefore all the files in it).  If you want to remove only certain files from the `target` directory, a combination of:

- `excludeDefaultDirectories` to stop it from deleting the whole directory, and
- `filesets` to tell it what to delete

ref: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html

Answer (score 12):

Solution with [Apache Maven AntRun Plugin 1.8](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <delete 
            dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}/resources"
            includeemptydirs="true"/>
        </target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This works for me also with deleting multiple files. For multiple files, i use 

                            <delete dir="$first-workspace"
    includeemptydirs="true"/>
    <delete 
    dir="$secondworkspace"
    includeemptydirs="true"/>

Answer (score 9):

I needed only a couple of files deleted from the output directory, the following worked fine for me.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/appContextLocal.xml" />
                    <delete
                        file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/appContextServer.xml" />
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I also figured that you can run any ant commands here replace what ever task you need in between the `<tasks> .... </tasks>` and it will work.

List of ant tasks that you can perform are [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasksoverview.html)

Ref: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 7):

thanks to above answers. finally i came to something like:

if you want to j**ust delete** ***some*** directories in target folder, you have to create some construct like this.
this for instance deletes just all contents of folders:

- target/unpack
- gen-external-apklibs

**excludeDefaultDirectories** allows to n**ot delete complete target folder**.
i used it to clean up target folder before lint analysis.

```
       <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Deleting all unnecessary files before lint analysis</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>target/unpack</directory>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>gen-external-apklibs</directory>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `<excludes/>` be `<includes/>` here? (And `<include/>` instead of `<exclude/>` of course.)