# Maven Xmlbeans Plugin - Generate & Retain files for specified schemas

Tags: maven, maven-3, xmlbeans, xmlbeans-maven-plugin

I'm trying to develop XML-based software. I'm using Maven & XmlBeans.

I have a `base-project` which provides `base-xml-schemas` which define some elements, abstract types, etc,.

All other `sub-projects` also provides xml-schemas. But, these sub-projects imports/refers the `base-xml-schemas` to use & extend the elements / types defined by `base-schemas`.

Even though my `sub-projects` *depends* on `base-project`, xmlbeans plugin requires the `base-xml-schemas` to be present in `schemaDirectory` for its usage. As an implication, all my sub-projects now carry the duplicate content generated/compiled due to `base-xml-schemas`.

I want my `sub-projects` to have only those sub-project-specific schemas & content in their jar, as My `base-project` will be available to all applications in my Jboss & the types can be resolved in runtime.

Having understood that the xmlbean needs all the schemas referred to be present for code generation, now I want to delete all xmlbean-generated code due to the present of `base-xml-schema` and retain files related to `sub-project` specific schemas.

I have manually done this and my project compilation & runtime works fine, as my maven has dependency & classes are available in runtime.

My question is - How to automate this using maven so the files generated due to `base-schema` is deleted just after generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven xmlbeans plugin binds by default to the lifecycle phase: generate-sources.

You will need to bind clean goal of the clean plugin to the above lifecycle phase.

Refer to the link - 
[Remove or delete resource files from target directory using pom file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637626/remove-or-delete-resource-files-from-target-directory-using-pom-file)

Configuration will be like this:

```
      <execution>
        <id>clean-autogenerated-code</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
         <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>some/relative/path/location/of/autogeneratd/code</directory>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

directory location - provide exact directory location of the auto-generated classes.

This you will need to configure in your all sub-projects from where you need to delete your auto-generated xml beans files. 
If you have any parent-pom all of your sub-projects, configure in that pom.xml file.