# How to skip reports & project info and not upload default skin's CSS & images?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-site-plugin

I would like to use Maven to upload the content of my website on Sourceforge, I don't want to generate and upload the reports, the project info, the CSS and the images of the skin. I have succeeded in generating no report but there are still the two unwanted directories containing the CSS and the images of the skin:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>myname</name>
  <description>mydescription</description>
  <url>http://www.somewhere.fr</url>
  <inceptionYear>2016</inceptionYear>

  <distributionManagement>
    <site>
      <id>myproject.sf.net</id>
      <url>scp://shell.sourceforge.net/home/project-web/myproject/htdocs/tmp/www_somewhere_fr</url>
    </site>
  </distributionManagement>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports></reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Question**: How can I get rid of those directories?

I tried the very last suggestion in [this tutorial](https://veithen.github.io/2013/05/04/maven-patterns-skipping-site-generation.html) but it doesn't work in my case. Setting `generateReports` and `generateProjectInfo` to `false` didn't help. Feel free to suggest a more appropriate plugin to do this task if maven-site-plugin isn't the right one.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get rid of those directories?

You could actually add some post-processing before deploying the site using the maven [phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) of the site lifecycle:

> - `pre-site`  execute processes needed prior to the actual project site generation
> - `site`    generate the project's site documentation
> - `post-site`   execute processes needed to finalize the site generation, and to prepare for site deployment
> - `site-deploy` deploy the generated site documentation to the specified web server

In this case the `post-site` phase sounds suitable for your requirements. You could hence bind plugin executions to the `post-site` phase for your post-processing, [deleting folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637626/remove-or-delete-resource-files-from-target-directory-using-pom-file), similar to the snippet below

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>auto-clean</id>
        <phase>post-site</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
         <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/folderToDelete</directory>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit discouraged. Maven isn't flexible enough for my project, I'll probably use Ant or Gradle to do it but I'll try your suggestion.